# How to export curved animation with Collada

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, collada

I made several animation and exported them with Collada and used in my mobile application.

But my last animation was using curve animation (some objects following a curve path) and I noticed that no animation has been exported.

The interesting thing was curve was not exported as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it.

By following actions below it is possible to export follow path animation.

Object ▶ Animation ▶ Bake Action...

Select "Clear Constrains", "Visual Keying" and "Bake Data" as "Object"

Then click ok.

Now the follow path animation can be exported.